# Google File Stream: "can’t mount to default mount point" error

Tags: hard-drive, streaming, google-drive

I get this error each time Google File Stream starts. I tried [creating a "DefaultMountPoint" reg key containing the desired drive letter as value](https://davidvielmetter.com/tips/google-file-stream-cant-mount-to-default-mount-point/), to no avail. Then I followed a [Google Adviser's recommendation to reinstall it by following every steps she listed](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/mFIDQQSHEYM), to no avail.

Help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post
[Drive File Stream "Can't mount to default mount point"](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/kaNJPLJV_ks)
adds more advice to your second link.

One entry says :

> 1. Go to `HKCU\Software\Google\DriveFS`
> 2. Add two Strings:
>
>    - name `ContentCachePath`, Value `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\DriveFS`
>    - name `DefaultMountPoint`, Value `H`
>
> NOTE> In my case this is H letter, but set the letter that DriveFS
>   should use. I assume, that this is the letter in the error.

A later entry adds :

> I discovered that there were two places in the registry on my computer that were pointing to a mount point for Drive File Stream.  Changing the mount point as indicated above did nothing, but then I found that `HKCU\software\Google\DriveFS\Share` had the incorrect drive letter as well.
>
> Once I changed this string to the proper drive letter I wanted, so that it matched the location stated above, I was able to reboot a number of times with no error.  This also fixed the problem on an older Windows 7 machine I have which started to exhibit the same issue in the past few days.

Comment: Worked, thanks! How convoluted though, what's wrong with Google? Why don't they fix that ASAP? I mean their app doesn't work by default on some machine, that's kind of problematic